# split midi file for each bar in python

Tags: python, midi, music21

I want to divide the MIDI file in python into bars and get the notes in that bars.
So I use music21 library and I can get the notes but I can't split it up by bar.
I want to know what kind of notes are in bar 1 and what are in bar 2.
I hope I can get some help with this problem.Thank you.

Comment: Please post your code showing your best attempt to reach a target. Each bar (measure) will have several channels (of voices, instruments). Focus only what you need.

Comment: With [DryWetMidi](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) (.NET library) you can split a MIDI file by grid with step of 1 bar and get notes for each new file: `var newFiles = midiFile.SplitByGrid(new SteppedGrid(new BarBeatTimeSpan(1, 0, 0))); var firstBarNotes = newFiles.First().GetNotes();`. Maybe in music21 there is something similar?

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of music21 (v7+ released after this question was first posted), you can just load the MIDI file and iterate on each measure, using the `.measure(num)` function and checking if the item returned has any measures in it:

```py
myScore = converter.parse('filename.mid')
i = 1
while (measureStack := myScore.measure(i))[stream.Measure]:
    print(len(measureStack[note.Note]))
    i += 1
```

Prior to v7, you'll want to run `myScore.makeMeasures(inPlace=True)` before running this code.  (Before v7, you'll also want to call `.recurse().getElementsByClass(XXXX)` instead of `[XXXX]`